# How to draw a line with color based on a numeric variable using Leaflet in R

Tags: r, leaflet, gis

What's up!

I have a data frame where each row I have the information of instant speed and coordinates (lat and long) of an object.

I'm trying to draw a line connecting all these lats and longs where the color of this line is the speed. Anyone can help me?

Here's some code:

```
require(leaflet)

df <- data.frame(Latitude = seq(14, 15, length.out = 100),
                 Longitude = seq(45, 46, length.out = 100),
                 Speed = runif(100, 50, 70))

pal <- colorNumeric(palette = "Greens", domain = df$Speed)

leaflet()%>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addPolylines(data = df,
                 lng = ~Longitude,
                 lat = ~Latitude,
                 color = ~pal(Speed))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)


df <- data.frame(lat = seq(14, 15, length.out = 100), 
                 lng = seq(45, 46, length.out = 100), 
                 Speed = runif(100, 50, 70))

pal <- colorNumeric(palette = "Greens", domain = df$Speed) 

colorGradient <- df$Speed %>%
  pal

df1 <- df %>%
  mutate(nextLat = lead(lat),
         nextLng = lead(lng),
         color = colorGradient
  )

gradient_map <- leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles()

for (i in 1:nrow(df1)) {
  gradient_map <- addPolylines(map = gradient_map,
                               data = df1, 
                               lng = as.numeric(df1[i, c('lng', 'nextLng')]), 
                               lat = as.numeric(df1[i, c('lat', 'nextLat')]), 
                               color = as.character(df1[i, c('color')])
  )
}

gradient_map
```

[Map Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZcgR.jpg)